# Power BI report help finilizing

Tags: powerbi

`enter code here`I am trying to make equipments availability report from 3 tables linked together by specific date, say for example (03/03/2019).

That date will return the jobs that we did in some equipments. When run the report I got only the equipments that have jobs on that day say I have 10 machines and I did only 3 jobs on that day so my result report will have only 3 rows I want my repor[The image show sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogi1J.png)t to have 10 rows with only 3 rows with information about the jobs.

On that day but I need my report to show all the equipments even those has no job on that day. In Access it is easy by editing the relationship properties and chose keep all records from first table.

Comment: Can you please update you question with sample data and an example of your desired outcome?

Comment: Would you update the title to read a specific question (removing the words "help please")? I was going to try to summarise it for you, but without an example, it is not very clear.